# How to properly close axios request in react redux application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Having **react** & **redux** application that using asynchronous calls via **Axios**, I need to cancel such request that are still in progress once the user navigate to other page or anything else. Being new to react I came up with an idea to keep the axios **cancelToken** in redux state and cancel it in `componentWillUnmount()` of the react component.

example:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  const (isLoading, cancelToken} = this.props;
  if (isLoading) {
    cancelToken.cancel("Abort request");
  }
}
```

Are there better patterns or solution to this?

EDIT:
Async call is being fired in redux-thunk i.e. action

Comment: Where exactly do you make these async calls, in component or in action creators

Comment: You might want to look into RxJS

Comment: Just added the information. Its in the middleware redux-thunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you have implemented your fetch.

If you have placed it within your component, you can fire the cancel event in the `componentWillUnmount` method.

If you have placed it in a middleware such as redux-saga, you can create and use the cancel token then and there itself.

If it is within an action creator you can try the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37464710/10052094)